# Logical Replication in PostgreSQL 10

Tags: postgresql, replication, subscription

Is it possible to create a Logical Replication in PostgreSQL 10 that I can just replicate a column from a table, like can I say to my create publication that I want just a column from that table ?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible.

How would you handle an `INSERT` or a `DELETE`?
How would you identify the row that should be modified with an `UPDATE`?

That said, you could define a `BEFORE` trigger `FOR EACH ROW` on the standby table that keeps all columns except the one you want to change at their original values. You'd have to use `ALTER TABLE ... ENABLE REPLICA TRIGGER` so that it is only activated during logical replication.